Quickest way to reach this position
Your friends Alice and Bob decided to play a chess game. Alice played as White and Bob played as Black.
The game reached the position shown below.

After that, you saw Alice (White) make a move and after a few more moves, Bob castled. All moves were legal.
Question: How quickly could the position shown in the image be reached?

This position can be reached in

 three moves, after 1. e4 e6 2. Bb5 c6 3. Bxc6 dxc6.


I’m confused.  OP said Black castled but your solution has no castling.

@Will.Octagon.Gibson Considering this accepted answer I assume it is supposed to be a 'read well' i.e. trick question. It is never stated that the position is reached after the castling. (or even that it is from Alice and Bob's game)

I edited it to clarify.

Black castles after this position is reached, so the Black king can't move.


e4 c6 2. Bc4 e6 3. Cxe6 dxe6

